# git and Angular 6 exclusion of folders

Tags: angular, git

I followed this basic sample on how to push files to VSTS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=vsts

I havent added any ignore files. Just the simple commands in the article. Of some reason node_modules, e2e and dist folders are ignored. I guess this is actually what i want, but how does my git know this? I have just made a simple ng new "ddd" is there anything in the angular files that ensures folders are ignored? I had a look and coundt find anything that looks like git ignore.

Comment: I believe that `ng new` will generate the `.gitignore` file for you

Comment: Do you know wher efiles are located?

Comment: Should be at the root of your angular project, at the same level as `package.json`, and the file will be called `.gitignore`. If you can't see it, it may be a hidden file, so make sure you can view hidden files

Comment: It was the hidden part, thanks alot! Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have just made a simple ng new "ddd" is there anything in the angular files that ensures folders are ignored?

When you create a new project with `ng new`, it generates a lot of files for you, one of which is `.gitignore`.

> I had a look and coundt find anything that looks like git ignore.

If you're on Windows, you're probably not seeing the file in Explorer because it's starts with `.`, which means that Windows treats it as a hidden files. Google around for a solution on *"windows show hidden files"* for your Windows version. You should see the `.gitignore` file in the root of the project `ddd`. It's a textual file, so you can open it with, for example, Notepad.